# Can the word "after" be used with the word "first"?

Tags: grammaticality

> I went there after going first to Eshwant Rao's house, where I met Raoji and the persons who usually went I mean Raoji, Karbhai, and Salam.

This sentence is from [Accounts and Papers of the House of Commons, Volume 56](https://books.google.com/books?id=cCxcAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA5-PA43). I wonder whether "after" can be used together with the word "first".

Comment: This is a fairly precise transcription of a non-native speaker's verbal testimony, so it is very likely to have errors. Also, it seems to be more than a hundred years old, so the usage is a little out of date.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, it depends how you want to order the sequence of events

> I went there **after first** going to the shop.
>   *I went to the shop before going elsewhere*
>
> I went there **first after** going to the shop.
>   *it was the first place I went to after going to the shop*